# Convert string of 0s and 1s to byte in Python

Tags: python, string, binary, byte, bit

I have a string representation of binary integers and I need bytes having the exact bit structure, to send over the sockets.

For e.g. if I have a string of length 16 : `0000111100001010` then I need 2 bytes of same bit structure. In this case, the first byte should have an int value of `15` and the second one as `10`. It doesn't matter if they can be printed in `ascii` format or not. How do I get it ?

I tried the following method which creates bytes in the form of `0xf0xa`. But this is of size 6 bytes instead of 2.

```
def getByte(s):
  if(len(s) != 8):
    return
  b = b'0'
  for c in s:
    b = (int(b) | int(c)) & 0x0000ff #This makes b an integer
    b = b << 1
  b = b >> 1 #because of 1 extra shift
  b = hex(b).encode('utf-8') #how else can I get back to byte from int?

  return(b)
```

This method takes a string of length 8 and intends to give a byte of the same internal bit structure, but fails. (I need something similar to `strtol` in `C`.)

Any help, please ?

Comment: `int('0000111100001010', 2)`. You can verify the value returned with `hex(int('0000111100001010', 2))`.

Comment: I need bytes. Not int.

Comment: `struct.pack('!H', int('0000111100001010', 2))`

Comment: That gives `b'\n\x0f'`. Somehow the lower byte is missing!

Comment: `'\n'` _is_ `0x0a`. Regardless what you really want is `'\x0f\n'` which is big-endian or network byte order (as in my updated `struct.pack` comment above).

Comment: @martineau you can put this as answer. This works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, if you have the bit string as a literal value, just make it a base-2 int literal, instead of a string literal:

```
value = 0b0000111100001010
```

---

If you have non-literal bit strings, and all you need to do is parse them into integers, then, as martineau says in a comment, the built-in [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) constructor is all you need, as martineau says, because it takes a `base` as an optional second argument:

```
value = int('0000111100001010', 2)
```

---

If you need to do anything fancy with bit strings, you'll probably want to use a third-party module like [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) or [`bitstring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/), which let you create objects that can be treated as strings of 1s and 0s, sequences of booleans, integers, etc.:

```
value = bitstring.BitArray(bin='0000111100001010')
```

---

Once you have an integer, you can pack it into 2 bytes with [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), as martineau also explained in a comment:

```
my_bytes = struct.pack('!H', value)
```

The `!` means "network-endian". If you want little-endian or native-endian (or big-endian, which is of course the same as network-endian, but might be a more meaningful way to describe some contexts), see [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). The `H` means to pack it as an C `unsigned short`—that is, two bytes.

---

But if you're using a third-party module, it probably has something simpler. For example, if you have a `bitstring.BitArray` from the previous example:

```
my_bytes = value.tobytes()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had used other libraries as bitstring. But at present 3rd party libraries can't be used for some reason.

Comment: @gaganbm: What do you mean "at present 3rd party libraries can't be used for some reason"? Do you get an error from `pip` when you try to install them, an error from `python` when you try to `import` them, an error from your boss/professor/whatever when you mention them in a meeting? If so, please post the full traceback from your boss so we can debug him. :)

Comment: @abarnet Oh, I meant to say I do not have the rights to install stuff in the systems I am using. More of an administrative pain :)

Comment: @gaganbm: You might want to consider using [user site-packages](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) and/or [`venv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)/[`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/) and/or some kind of `cx_freeze`/`py2exe`/`py2app`-style packaged distribution to get around that problem. (In fact, in many scenarios, that's a good idea even if you _do_ have root/admin rights on all of the target machines.)

Comment: @abarnert: You don't need to install bitstring at all - it's all in one .py file so an alternative is to just download it and store it in the same directory to your main program.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths: Good point. The same is not true for `bitarray`; it's a C extension that you have to build. But even there, you can always `build_ext -i` it and copy the `bitarray` package (a directory with `__init__.py` and `_bitarray.so` inside) alongside your main program. For either library, I wouldn't normally encourage doing things that way, but you're definitely right to point out that it's an option.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to convert binary string data like the one you have is to use the built-in `int()` function and tell it the number is in base 2 binary instead of the default base 10 decimal format:

```
int('0000111100001010', 2)
```

This will return a an integer value. To convert that into a string of bytes you can use the `pack()` function in the `struct` mode and tell it the data argument it a `short` (2-byte) unsigned integer by using a format string of `'H'`:

```
struct.pack('!H', int('0000111100001010', 2))
```

Since you want to send this over a network socket, I also added a `'!'` prefix, which indicates that the bytes returned should be in "network" or big-endian byte-order rather than the native format of your computer (which might be different).

Note the string returned for the example will be `'\x0f\n'`. The `'\n'` at the end is because the byte value `0x0a` happens to be an ASCII newline character so Python represents them that way when it displays the `repr()` of a string that contains one (which is what the Python interactive console does after every expression automatically).